# Hibernate 5 and various informix versions

Tags: hibernate, informix

I’m must work with informix v9, v12, etc (various departments)

There is no problem with informix v12. When I get connection to informix v9, hibernate looks for syssequences table and couldn’t find it, because for this version infromix this system table has name SYSSYNTABLE

```
(ERROR: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database java.sql.SQLException: The specified table (syssequences) is not in the database.)
```

How can I override this table in configuration file?

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.dep.db.entity" />
    
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect </prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
```

Comment: To what versions of Informix v9 are you referring? Informix 9.40 does have sequences and the syssequences table. Versions of 9.30 and earlier do not. Note that all versions of 9 are out of support.
The syssyntable relates to synonyms not sequences so is not a substitute for syssequences. 
I don't know how hibernate works with sequences but if all it is doing is looking for information about sequences then, if you are using Informix 9.30 or earlier, you could create an empty table with the same name and schema as in 12.10 so that the query run by hibernate will return 0 rows.

Comment: I’m reffering to informix v9.21. 
Creating tables is bad idea because there are too many departments in my company with various informix versions. I’ve thought about it.

Thanx for response

Comment: Your question mentions version 9.12 — that was obsolete before Y2K.  Version 9.21 mentioned in a comment was Y2K-compliant.  I trust you are not dealing with 9.12. Frankly, the thought that you have to deal with 9.21 is scary — versions 9.30, 9.40, 10.00, 11.10, and 11.50 have all been made obsolete since 9.21 was made obsolete.  Version 11.70 goes out of service (will become obsolete) in September 2020 — you should be avoiding that, too.